# Initializing global paths in the env.rb file (ruby/cucumber)

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Trying to create the initial config for a cucumber/ruby test framework and I was thinking about defining some global paths in the env.rb file as follow:

```
def project_path
 File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../')
end

def config_path
 "#{project_path}/features/support/config"
end
```

thinking about then invoking those Paths from the ruby code.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to run the tests, they fail with:

```
undefined local variable or method `config_path' for Configuration:Class (NameError)
```

I suppose that 'config_path' is not define before the module/class is trying to use it? Is there a way to indicate that we'd like everything in the env.rb file to be processed before anything else is done? (Not sure if this is even been done already and the failure is in another point?)

Answer (score 1):

try this in env.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "cucumber"
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')

require 'cucumber/formatter/unicode'
require 'cucumber/rails/world'
require 'cucumber/rails/active_record'
require 'cucumber/web/tableish'
require 'webrat'
require 'webrat/core/matchers'

Webrat.configure do |config|
 config.mode = :rails
 config.open_error_files = false   
end

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```